# How can I merge two methods sequentially in a single one?

Tags: java, object, if-statement, merge, void

Good afternoon ! Here I have  2 Java objects in a class, but I have no clue how can I merge them together, so in the end result the will be just one single public void verifyRoom2() object...
`

```
public void verifyRoom2()
    {
        if (number.trim().startsWith("00") || number.trim().startsWith("99")) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not valid");
        }
    }
    
    public void verifyRoom3() {
         if ('A' == number.charAt(2) || ('B' == number.charAt(2)) || ('C' == number.charAt(2))) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not valid");
        }
    }
```

`
Many thanks everyone ! <3

I tried to merge these methods sequentially together so at the end result there will be just one single public void verifyRoom2() method.

Comment: Those are methods, not objects. "How" do you want to merge them? Do you want to execute them sequentially? Interleaved? In random order? Nested? Something else? We don't really know what your expected result is and why you cannot append the body of `verifyRoom3` to the body of `verifyRoom2`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I just started Java and it`s my first ever project... Wil try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an answer because a comment is a too small. What about changing the signature.

```
public boolean verifyRoom2(){
    return number.trim().startsWith("00") || number.trim().startsWith("99"));
}

public boolean verifyRoom3() {
     return ('A' == number.charAt(2) || ('B' == number.charAt(2)) || ('C' == number.charAt(2))); 
}
```

Now you can test both methods. (this could be your "merged" method)

```
if( verifyRoom2() && verifyRoom3() ){
    System.out.println("valid");
} else{
    System.out.println("at least one room is invalid.");
}
```

It's odd that you use `.trim()` in one method, and not in the other.